# Prove that product of a nilpotent group and a supersolvable group is a supersolvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Suppose that $G$ is a finite group, and $G = HK$, where $H,K \triangleleft G$, $H$ is a nilpotent group, $K$ is supersolvable group. Prove that $G$ is supersolvable group.

Thanks.

(The group $G$ is said *supersolvable* if it has normal series $G_{0}\triangleleft G_{1}\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft G_{n}=G$ such that $G_{i}\triangleleft G$ and $G_{i}/G_{i-1}$ is cyclic for all $i = 0,1,2,...,n$.)

PS. I knew that if $H$ and $K$ are supersolvable, normal subgroups of $G$, then $HK$ is not necessary supersolvable, but in this case it is supersolvable.

Comment: Hint: Nilpotent and Finitely generated is supersolvable.

Comment: @W4cc0 , that still doesn't solve the problem as a product of two normal supersolvable group may *not* be supersolvable...

Comment: @DonAntonio You're right...

Comment: In fact, not even the product of two nilpotent (finite) subgroups necessarily is supersolvable. I can tell that if the indices of $\;H,K\;$ in $\;G\;$ are coprime then their product is supersolvable. The same is true if we have that $\;G'\;$ is nilpotent...

Comment: @DonAntonio : If $H$ and $K$  are nilpotent, then their product is nilpotent (Fitting). (I assume that you did not assumed that $H$ and $K$ are normal)

Comment: Yes @YassineGuerboussa, I know that...so?

Comment: Yes, @DonAntonio, if the indices of $H,K$ in $G$ are coprime then their product is supersolvable, but I do not connect it with my problem. I think in case $H$ is nilpotent group, $K$ is supersolvable group, we can show that $HK$ has a supersoluble series, because $H$ has a central series, and $K$ is supersolvable (so it has a supersoluble series), but I do not have a solution. Give me a hand, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the intersection of the groups in the lower central series of $H$ with $K$. The terms in this series are all normal in $G$. Since $K$ is supersolvable, we can refine this to a series in which all terms are normal in $K$ and the factor groups are cyclic. But because we have refined a series in which the factors are all centralized by $H$, the resulting terms are all normal in $H$ too. So we have found a series for $H \cap K$ with cyclic factor groups in which all terms are normal in $G$.

But $G/(H \cap K) \cong H/(H \cap K) \times K/(H \cap K)$ is a direct prodict of a nilpotent group and a supersolvable group, so it is supersolvable. Hence $G$ is supersolvable.

*Added later*: To see that the terms in the refinement are normalized by $H$,
note that $(\gamma_iH \cap K)/(\gamma_{i+1}H \cap K) \le Z(H/(\gamma_{i+1}H \cap K))$. So any subgroup of $(\gamma_iH \cap K)/(\gamma_{i+1}H \cap K)$ is normal in $H/(\gamma_{i+1}H \cap K)$. Hence any group $K_i$ with $\gamma_{i+1}H \cap K \le K_i \le \gamma_iH \cap K$ is normal in $H$.

Comment: It is a good idea, but I do not understand this text "...we have refined a series in which the factors are all centralized by $H$, the resulting terms are all normal in $H$ too", suppose that we refined and we have a series:   
$K\geq H\cap K=\gamma_{1}H \cap K \geq K _{1} \geq K_{2}\geq...\geq K_{m} \geq \gamma_{2}H \cap K \geq...\geq \gamma_{n}H \cap K =1$ (*)  
(where $H=\gamma_{1}H \geq \gamma_{2}H \geq ...\geq \gamma_{n}H =1$ is a lower central series of $H$)  Why $K_{i}$ is normal in $H$ ? Could you please explain the normal in $H$ of terms to me more clearly? Thank you so much.

Comment: I've added some more explanation!

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you very much!