# Direct Product of a nilpotent group with a supersolvable group is supersolvable

Tags: group-theory, direct-product, nilpotent-groups

Let $H$ be a nilpotent group and $K$ a supersolvable group. Considering $G=H \times K$, then $G$ is supersolvable.

I tried to create a normal cyclic series, but I don't know how to proceed, maybe the idea is to create a specific one. If group H were finite, it would be supersolvable and the exercise would follow.

Comment: Set $K=1$. Is your claim true?

Comment: It really is not valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even abelian groups need not be supersolvable. For instance, the additive group of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ is not supersolvable. So nilpotent groups need not be supersolvable. In particular $G=H\times K=\Bbb Q\times 1$ is not supersolvable, although $K=1$ is supersolvable and $H=\Bbb Q$ is nilpotent.

I suspect that you mean the claim of the duplicate below (where the product is $G=HK$ of finite groups, and with normal subgroups).

[Prove that product of a nilpotent group and a supersolvable group is a supersolvable group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516529/prove-that-product-of-a-nilpotent-group-and-a-supersolvable-group-is-a-supersolv)

Comment: The important point there is that the groups in your linked question are finite. The statement holds if $H$ and $K$ are finitely generated, not in general.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: I really wanted to prove that the $HK$ product is supersolvable, but this point (direct product) appeared in the link you sent. Thanks! I realized that actually this result holds considering $H$ finitely generated, it doesn't need $K$ to be either.